# curly braces around set of nodes with some text

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, braces

Is it possible to put curly braces around a set of nodes with some text near the bottom right of the brace.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,positioning,fit}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[text width=3cm]                       (A)  at (0,0)               {\tiny AAA};
    
    \node[anchor=north west , text width=1cm]   (A1) at (A.south west)      {\tiny BBB};
    \node[anchor=west       , text width=1cm]   (A2) at (A1.east)           {\tiny CCC};
    \node[anchor=west       , text width=1cm]   (A3) at (A2.east)           {\tiny DDD};
    
    \node[anchor=north west , text width=1cm]   (A4) at (A1.south west)     {\tiny EEE};
    \node[anchor=west       , text width=1cm]   (A5) at (A4.east)           {\tiny FFF};
    \node[anchor=west       , text width=1cm]   (A6) at (A5.east)           {\tiny };
    
    \node [inner sep=0pt,
            draw,
            rounded corners,
            fit = (A)(A1)(A2)(A3)(A4)(A5)(A6)
            ] (A13) {}; 
    
    \draw   (A1.north west) -- (A3.north east)
    (A1.south west) -- (A3.south east);    
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image: braces around nodes]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,positioning,fit}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing} % <--- add this

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[text width=3cm]                       (A)  at (0,0)               {\tiny AAA};
    
    \node[anchor=north west , text width=1cm]   (A1) at (A.south west)      {\tiny BBB};
    \node[anchor=west       , text width=1cm]   (A2) at (A1.east)           {\tiny CCC};
    \node[anchor=west       , text width=1cm]   (A3) at (A2.east)           {\tiny DDD};
    
    \node[anchor=north west , text width=1cm]   (A4) at (A1.south west)     {\tiny EEE};
    \node[anchor=west       , text width=1cm]   (A5) at (A4.east)           {\tiny FFF};
    \node[anchor=west       , text width=1cm]   (A6) at (A5.east)           {\tiny };
    
    \node [inner sep=0pt,
            draw,
            rounded corners,
            fit = (A)(A1)(A2)(A3)(A4)(A5)(A6)
            ] (A13) {}; 
    
    \draw   (A1.north west) -- (A3.north east)
    (A1.south west) -- (A3.south east);    
    
    \draw [red,thick,decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,mirror,raise=1ex}]
  (A13.north west) -- (A13.south west) ;
  
    \draw [red,thick,decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,raise=1ex}]
  (A13.north east) -- (A13.south east) node[right,xshift=0.5em]{your text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also just use a matrix, which offers these curly brackets as delimiters, and is a perhaps more natural way of arranging the texts "AAA", "BBB" and so on.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \matrix[matrix of nodes,column sep=1.5em,draw,rounded corners=4pt,
    left delimiter=\{,right delimiter=\}](m){
  AAA & & \\
  BBB & CCC & DDD\\
  EEE & FFF & \\
 };
 \path (m-1-1) -- coordinate (aux1) (m-2-1) -- coordinate (aux2) (m-3-1)
  foreach \x in {1,2}{(aux\x-|m.west) edge (aux\x-|m.east)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]